# How to avoid triggering events in discord.py?

Tags: python, events, discord.py

I want my bot to reconnect to a voice channel when it disconnects, so I am using this code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if member.id == bot.id and after.channel == None and before.channel != None:
        voiceChannel = before.channel #get the channel to reconnect to
        await voiceChannel.connect()  #reconnect to that voice channel
```

which works fine, but when I try to disconnect the bot from the code:
`await voiceChannel.disconnect()`, the bot rejoins the voice channel. So is there any way that I can avoid triggering `on_voice_state_update`?

What I have tried:

- Reading through the first two pages of google results of `discord.py avoid triggering event` and `discord.py avoid triggering on_voice_state_update`
- Reading through the [discord.py event documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference)
- Searching `[discord.py] avoid triggering event` on this website.

From this I got no useful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a boolean to check if it was disconnected intentionally or it needs to be reconnected.
I'm assuming that the disconnecting part is a command:

```py
# Put this variable at the top of the entire code
disconnecting = False # You can also make this as an attribute of the bot instance

@bot.command()
async def disconnect(ctx):
    # ... Code before
    disconnecting = True
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if disconnecting:
        disconnecting = False  # Reset the variable for future use.
        return # Do not let the following occur
    if member.id == bot.id and after.channel == None and before.channel != None:
        voiceChannel = before.channel #get the channel to reconnect to
        await voiceChannel.connect()  #reconnect to that voice channel
```

Answer (score -1):

May be it does't work, but you can add some flag like `disconnect_flag` which help
to recognize disconnect case. If you `disconnect_flag is True` don't call voiceChannel.connect()

Comment: But how do I add flags in this case? Because I don't call `on_voice_state_update` manually, so I can't just add the argument `disconnect_flag`